# Parsing a difficult sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding this sentence from a book on system theory, which reads like a modern version of Euclid's Elements:

> Intuitively, we would expect the concept of a system to involve some
>   kind of inter-relation between the percepts it generates, and which
>   then become identified with corresponding relationships between the
>   external qualities which generated them.

The idiomatic construction would be "inter-relation between `x` and `y`" but the meaning of "inter-relation between the percepts" seems to be "a set of relations among a set of percepts" because there is no noun `y` to follow. Here is my attempt at a paraphrase, with parentheses to identify nouns:

`The concept of a system involves
(a set S of
  (relations among
    (a set of
      (percepts generated by the system))))
such that S becomes "identified with"
(a set of
  (relations among
    (a set of
      (external qualities generated the percepts)))).`

Does this seem right?

Comment: *Become* is not 3d person singular, so its subject can only be the plural *percepts*: it is the *percepts* which *become identified...*  You're probably confused by that superfluous *and*, which improperly suggests that *become* and *involve* are parallel.

Comment: What is generating what? Is the system generating the percepts or are the the external qualities generating the percepts? To what noun does the final word "them" refer?

Comment: [Here's the source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=C81GBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA46&dq=%22between+the+external+qualities+which+generated+them%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bGtnVYqTH_SKsQTd44OoBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22between%20the%20external%20qualities%20which%20generated%20them%22&f=false). If OP is having difficulty understanding what the writer means, that's probably just because the *Ideas* being discussed are complex, not because the words themselves need "explaining". So I think this is Off Topic philosophy, not "language use" as such.

Comment: The idea described here is self-evident, if I understand it rightly: the author's saying that when we make a simplified model of a system, we expect the symbols and relationships in our model to shed light on the original system. But the author uses "between" where he means "among", he has that disorienting "and", and he uses some odd vocabulary. (Terms of art in his discipline, maybe? Why can't they use the vocabulary of set theory, or of Aristotle?) But modern academic prose puts a low value on lucidity...

Comment: @ExOttoyuhr: I see no reason to favour, say, [*arguments **among** family members*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22arguments+among+family+members%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) over [*arguments **between** family members*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22arguments+between+family+members%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). In fact, Google Books has twice as many instances of the latter, and I bet almost none of them are contexts that continue with *...between family members **and** [others from outside the family]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: At least to my ear, "between" suggests something dual about its referents. "Arguments between family members" sounds like two family members are quarreling; "arguments among family members" could involve the whole family. In this case, there are more than two percepts generated, the percepts can have relationships with multiple others, these relationships can be non-binary, _and the reader might assume that only binary relationships exist_; thus my saying that the author means "among."

Comment: @ExOttoyuhr: I think you read too much into it. It's true only ***between*** can be used where there are exactly two parties (you can't have *an argument **among** Jack and Jill*, for example). But both prepositions work equally well in most other contexts, and if I read that there's *disagreement between politicians* I don't necessarily have any opinion as to whether there's one disagreement (between two separate groups of politicians) or multiple disagreements. The surrounding context would normally make it obvious, if the difference *made* any difference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "A disagreement between politicians" sounds unnatural to me. I'd expect "a disagreement between two politicians," "among politicians," or "between two groups of politicians."

Comment: @ExOttoyuhr: Google Books thinks it has 344 instances of [*disagreement between politicians*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22disagreement+between+politicians%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22disagreement+between+politicians%22&tbm=bks&start=10), compared to 483 of [*disagreement among politicians*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22disagreement+among+politicians%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and glancing at a few pages of the former it looks like about half of them are *...between politicians **and** [journalists, etc.]*, so I agree you have a point. But both usages occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The idiomatic construction would be "inter-relation between x and y"
>   but the meaning of "inter-relation between the percepts" seems to be
>   "a set of relations among a set of percepts" because there is no noun
>   y to follow.

X and Y are, in this case, combined into a single plural term (since there's no natural way to distinguish between percepts in this kind of general statement).

This is a very awkwardly constructed sentence.

Comment: I'm guessing that "inter-relation" would be contrasted with "relation" in this usage; an inter-relation applying to a collective, a relation applying to a pair.

Comment: @kdsch: my thoughts as well, and this further underlines how "between" is a very strange word choice here.